# Video Source file from YouTube crashes app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-video-player, android-videoview

App works fine when video is in the raw folder with media controllers. But when I put an embed src value from a Youtube video inside setVideoPath paranthesis, the app crashes. Please help!

```
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.widget.VideoView;
     import android.widget.MediaController;
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VideoView vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    vid.setVideoPath("https://www.youtube.com/embed/8iPFYfXuygk");
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(vid);
    vid.setMediaController(mediaController);
    vid.start();
}
```

}

Comment: are you testing on emulator ?

Comment: why dont you try https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: if you want play a youtube video then i think you have to refer a direct mp4 link on youtube or default video can not play short url as above

Comment: @BilalShahid: No I'm using a phone for testing. Yeah I think that makes more sense. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Example](http://www.truiton.com/2013/08/android-videoview-example-with-youtube-playback/) code working fine for youetube Video play using videoview

```
package com.truiton.videoview;

    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

    import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.MediaController;
    import android.widget.VideoView;

    public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity {
        private VideoView videoView;
        private MediaController mController;
        private Uri uriYouTube;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_view);
            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
            mController = new MediaController(this);
            videoView.setMediaController(mController);
            videoView.requestFocus();

            /*Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/"
                    + R.raw.sample);
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            videoView.start();*/

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                int loc = savedInstanceState.getInt("Loc");
                Log.i("Loaction: ", loc + "");
                uriYouTube = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("url"));
                videoView.setVideoURI(uriYouTube);
                videoView.seekTo(loc);
                videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        Log.v("onPrepared", "ok");
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                RTSPUrlTask truitonTask = new RTSPUrlTask();
                truitonTask.execute("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zNSgSzhBfM");
            }

        }

        void startPlaying(String url) {
            uriYouTube = Uri.parse(url);
            videoView.setVideoURI(uriYouTube);
            videoView.start();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt("Loc", videoView.getCurrentPosition());
            outState.putString("url", uriYouTube.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.video_view, menu);
            return true;
        }

        private class RTSPUrlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                String response = getRTSPVideoUrl(urls[0]);
                return response;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                startPlaying(result);
            }

            public String getRTSPVideoUrl(String urlYoutube) {
                try {
                    String gdy = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
                    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                            .newDocumentBuilder();
                    String id = extractYoutubeId(urlYoutube);
                    URL url = new URL(gdy + id);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();
                    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
                    Element el = doc.getDocumentElement();
                    NodeList list = el.getElementsByTagName("media:content");
                    String cursor = urlYoutube;
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                        Node node = list.item(i);
                        if (node != null) {
                            NamedNodeMap nodeMap = node.getAttributes();
                            HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < nodeMap.getLength(); j++) {
                                Attr att = (Attr) nodeMap.item(j);
                                maps.put(att.getName(), att.getValue());
                            }
                            if (maps.containsKey("yt:format")) {
                                String f = maps.get("yt:format");
                                if (maps.containsKey("url"))
                                    cursor = maps.get("url");
                                if (f.equals("1"))
                                    return cursor;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return cursor;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    return urlYoutube;
                }
            }

            public String extractYoutubeId(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
                String query = new URL(url).getQuery();
                String[] param = query.split("&");
                String id = null;
                for (String row : param) {
                    String[] param1 = row.split("=");
                    if (param1[0].equals("v")) {
                        id = param1[1];
                    }
                }
                return id;
            }
        }


    }
```

Add add permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```